# PictureBox BackgroundImage Property C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

can someone please refresh me how I can programatically set the background image of a picture box?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picture Box have both `Image` and `Background Image` Property

to set `Background Image` you have to set `pictureBox1.BackgroundImage=your_Image;`

and for `Image` property `pictureBox1.Image=your_Image;`

Comment: thanks for this. what if I wanted to use an image which is found in my application's Resources file? how will I be able to access it programatically?

Comment: namespace_name.Properties.Resources.Your_Image;

Comment: What is the difference in functionality of Image and Background Image?

Answer (score 4):

[`PictureBox.Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx)

--Update

You need an image object.  You can use the static function image.fromfile

[`PictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(Path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx)

Comment: i know this but i just don't know the exact syntax which would include the source of the image.