# Load image from url to picturebox background

Tags: c#, picturebox

I found some easy ways to load image to picturebox but I couldn't find an easy way to load image to picturebox backround.

If you know any easier example than this...

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/image.jpg");

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    pictureBox1.BackroundImage = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
}
```

...please share it.

The two easy ways to load image from url to picturebox are...

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg";

pictureBox1.Load(url);
```

But I cannot use them

The reason that I want to use **BackroundImage** instead of **Image** is that I want to stretch the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to strech your image to fit the PictureBox you can [`PictureBox.SizeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx) to [`StretchImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx).

This will work when you specify your image using the `pictureBox1.ImageLocation` property or the `pictureBox1.Load()` method.

Comment: Yes I know that.. this is the example that I will use if i not find easier... I just copy paste without change it.. Sorry

Comment: @Loclip hmm, then I'm not fully understanding your question -- not sure if you can get easier than what I show.  Is there another problem I'm not seeing?

Comment: I put the two easy ways by using .Image.. I just wanted to know if there is anything easy like that for .BackroundImage

Comment: Thank you very much... I didn't know that I can stretch image without using BackgroundImage... Thank you again... :D

Answer (score 1):

As easy as :

pictureBox1.BackgroundImage=your_Image;

For more info check here

1.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage.aspx

or

2.
Picture Box have both Image and Background Image Property

to set Background Image you have to set pictureBox1.BackgroundImage=your_Image;

and for Image property pictureBox1.Image=your_Image;
from here: [PictureBox BackgroundImage Property C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116743/picturebox-backgroundimage-property-c-sharp)

Comment: I can't use pictureBox1.BackgroundImage=your_Image because my image is web url